# Validation rule that allow only number along with a specific string

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I want a validation rule that should allow only number (0-9) and a specific string ('N/A') which contains a special character also.

```
NOT(REGEX(Code__c, "[0-9,;N/A]*"))
```

The above validation rule is not working.

Comment: Not sure of the regex grammar support, so this is a comment not an answer. Try "[0-9]+|[Nn]/[Aa]" which means one or more numeric digits OR N/A in a case insensitive manner.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "[0-9]+|[Nn]/[Aa]" which means one or more numeric digits OR N/A in a case insensitive manner.